# What Private key and public key inside Keystore file

Tags: keystore, keytool, private-key, public-key

Can you tell me more clearly about public key and private key from below code::

```
>keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore2.jks -storepass password -validity 9360 -keysize 2048

What is your first and last name?
[Unknown]: CLARK
What is the name of your organizational unit?
[Unknown]: OO
What is the name of your organization?
[Unknown]: O
What is the name of your City or Locality?
[Unknown]: JUMO
What is the name of your State or Province?
[Unknown]: TU
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
[Unknown]: PA
Is CN=clark, OU=OO, O=O, L=jumo, ST=TU, C=PA correct?
[no]: yes

Enter key password for 
(RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

From the above example, what is the PrivateKey and what is the PublicKey?? 
**Please explain which part belongs PrivateKey and which part belongs PublicKey in above Keystore.jks file ?**

Answer (score 0):

As fas as i understood that.
A keystore file can contains Keys, KeyPairs, Trusted Certificates.

Here keys are the SecretKey like privateKeys only.
KeyPairs are the combination of PrivateKeys and Certificate(contain PublicKey).
TrustedCertificate are the certificate can contains PublicKeys only.

*Any more details appreciated!*

Answer (score 0):

See the Oracle documentation for [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html#CertChains)